# Using Insertion Sort return in sorted order the k smallest elements of an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm prepping for software developer job interviews and reviewing algorithm questions. I can't figure out how to modify an Insertion Sort algorithm so that it returns in sorted order the *k* smallest elements of an array of size *n*.

**Insertion Sort algorithm**

```
for i = 1 to n
  j = i
  while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
    swap A[j] and A[j-1]
    j = j - 1
```

Adding a for loop to the end of the algorithm to get the first *k* elements doesn't count.

Comment: Consider adding a break condition in the outer loop maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With normal insertion sort, you loop from start to end, and each item is
moved up until it's in place. With this insertion sort, you still loop
from start to end, but if the item you're on is >= the kth item, just
leave it; if less, move it to position *k*, then move it up until it's
in place.

```
for i = 1 to k
  j = i
  while j > 1 and A[j-1] > A[j]
    swap A[j] and A[j-1]
    j = j - 1
```

First *k* items are now sorted.

```
for i = k + 1 to n
  if A[i] < A[k]
    swap A[i] and A[k]
    j = k
    while j > 1 and A[j-1] > A[j]
      swap A[j] and A[j-1]
      j = j - 1
```

Comment: @PhamTrung: This algorithm is correct. You can try it on your input.

Comment: @justhalf Oh, yes, I misunderstood the second part, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, the original code and this have the same problem: indices start at 1, and we will sometimes check A[0]. Working on it...

Comment: Or you can just insert `if i > k then { swap A[k+1] and A[i]; j = k + 1 }` after `j = i` in the original code.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: That's a nice hack. Seems like it would move more data than my version, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: @TomZych: Yes, it would.  You could actually just copy `A[i]` to `A[k+1]` instead of swapping them, since all we care about are the top k entries, but that's still more data movement than your approach.

Comment: Hmm, we're assuming 0-based indices, right? The original algorithm works with 0-indexed array (assuming `1 to n` means like `range` in Python, that is, the `n` is not included. Haha)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to execute the inner loop selectively for elements k+1 to n. Almost same as the previous solution but avoids some duplicating code.

```
for i = 1 to n
    j = i

    if i < k or A[i] < A[k]
        while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
            swap A[j] and A[j-1]
            j = j - 1
```